# Singleton pattern in baseclass-subclass scenario

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, design-patterns, singleton

I am under the impression that, using Singleton pattern I can limit the number of  instantiation of a class to one object. And keeping that in mind, have a look at the below code:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]

class base1(object):
    __metaclass__ = Singleton

class base2(base1):
    pass

class base3(base1):
    pass

class base4(base2):
    pass        

obj1 = base4()
obj2 = base4()

print obj1 is obj2 #prints True

obj3 = base3()
obj4 = base3()

print obj3 is obj4 #prints True

print obj1 is obj3 #prints False
```

First print statement prints `True` which proves that `obj3` and `obj4` are same object. But the second print statement prints `False` proving `obj1` and `obj3` are not same. What could be the best way to go ahead in achieving the goal, `"Always return the same base1 object no matter which sub class instantiates it"`.

Comment: Why would you even have these subclasses? Heck, if you really want to go through the metaclass-based enforcement route of doing singletons, why are you even allowing these subclasses to exist?

Comment: That does not make sense! Why do you even create multiple classes if all of them should only be able to create an object of their base? Do you perhaps want an alias for the base class? Your code is specifically built to allow one singleton **for each** class in the hierarchy. Why did you program it like that in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

The code was copied from [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/141933-forbidding-inheritance/).

You can create a `terminal` class and use it as a `__metaclass__` so other classes can't inherit from it:

```
class terminal(type):
    def __init__(self, cl_name, bases, namespace):
        for cls in bases:
            if isinstance(cls, terminal):
                raise TypeError("in "+cl_name+" definition : "+str(cls)+
                                " can't be used as a base class")
        super(terminal, self).__init__(cl_name, bases, namespace)


# first we create a normal class
class a(object):
    pass

#the terminal class: it can inherit from other classes but can't be
#used as base class
class b(a):
    __metaclass__= terminal

#this will fail because inheriting from b is forbidden
class c(b):
    pass
```

Comment: When exactly is that "compile" time? Class creation happens at run time!

Comment: @Wombatz  code comment - fixed. Other than that, can you explain the why do you think it's not a good answer ?